# What is a Recordset in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-8

What is a recordset in Odoo and how it is different from a model?

Also, when we create a model and a method inside it, so when does it gets executed and by whom, I mean where is the instance of that model?

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environment.html#recordset

> All instances of Model are at the same time instances of a RecordSet. A Recordset represents a sorted set of records of the same Model as the RecordSet.